# Folium chloropleth map only showing grey - help to troubleshoot

Tags: python, folium

I having trouble getting some air pollution data to show different colors in a chloropleth map using folium. Please let me know where my code may be throwing an error. I think it is the key_on parameter but need help.

This is how my map turns out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJbHN.png)

What I would like is for the mean concentration of the air pollution data to show up on the map but the map is still greyed out.

Here are the files I used:

1. Geojson file - Used "download zip" in upper right of this website https://gist.github.com/miguelpaz/edbc79fc55447ae736704654b3b2ef90#file-uhf42-geojson
2. Data file - Exported data from here https://a816-dohbesp.nyc.gov/IndicatorPublic/VisualizationData.aspx?id=2023,719b87,122,Summarize

   Here is my code:

> import geopandas as gpd
> import folium
>
> ```
> #clean pollution data
> pm_df1 = pd.read_csv('/work/Fine Particulate Matter (PM2.5).csv',header = 5, usecols = ['GeoTypeName', 'Borough','Geography', 'Geography ID','Mean (mcg per cubic meter)'], nrows = 140)
>
> #limit dataframe to rows with neighborhood (UHF 42) that matches geojson file
> pm_df2 = pm_df1[(pm_df1['GeoTypeName'] == 'Neighborhood (UHF 42)')]
> pm_df2
>
> #clean geojson file
> uhf_df2 = gpd.read_file('/work/uhf42.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
> uhf_df2.head()
>
> #drop row 1 that has no geography
> uhf_df3 = uhf_df2.iloc[1:]
> uhf_df3.head()
>
> ## create a map
> pm_testmap = folium.Map(location=[40.65639,-73.97379], tiles = "cartodbpositron", zoom_start=10)
>
> # generate choropleth map 
> pm_testmap.choropleth(
>     geo_data=uhf_df3,
>     data=pm_df2,
>     columns=['Geography', 'Mean (mcg per cubic meter)'],
>     key_on='feature.properties.uhf_neigh',  #think this is where I mess up.
>     fill_color='BuPu', 
>     fill_opacity=0.2, 
>     line_opacity=0.7,
>     legend_name='Average dust concentration',
>     smooth_factor=0)
>
> # display map
> pm_testmap
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with key_on is right as you think.
Both data have the name of UHF written on them, but in a completely different form.
In order to link these two, the data must first be preprocessed.
I don't know your data.
It would be nice if you could `df.head()` the two data to show them, but I'll explain based on the data I checked through the link you provided.

In your geojson file, uhf_neigh simply says `Northeast Bronx`. However, your PM data appears to have the region listed as `Bronx: Northeast Bronx`. The following process seems to be necessary to unify your local name before plotting map.

```
uhf_df2['UHF_NEIGH'] = uhf_df2['BOROUGH']+ ': ' + uhf_df2['UHF_NEIGH']
```

Comment: Thank you Urban87  and r-beginners

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run it with your data and code, but it was not even displaying the map. There should be no problem in your code because you have associated the place name in the data frame with the place name in geojson. I gave up on the string association and changed the association to a place name code association, and the map was displayed. The provided csv file failed to load, so I deleted the unnecessary lines and loaded it. Also, I read the file as a json file instead of geopandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import folium

pm_df1 = pd.read_csv('./data/test_20211221.csv')
pm_df1 = pm_df1[['GeoTypeName', 'Borough', 'Geography', 'Geography ID', 'Mean (mcg per cubic meter)']]
pm_df2 = pm_df1[(pm_df1['GeoTypeName'] == 'Neighborhood (UHF 42)')]

with open('./data/uhf42.geojson') as f:
    uhf_df3 = json.load(f)
    
pm_testmap = folium.Map(location=[40.65639,-73.97379], tiles = "cartodbpositron", zoom_start=10)

# generate choropleth map 
pm_testmap.choropleth(
    geo_data=uhf_df3,
    data=pm_df2,
    columns=['Geography ID', 'Mean (mcg per cubic meter)'],
    key_on='feature.properties.uhfcode',  #think this is where I mess up.
    fill_color='BuPu', 
    fill_opacity=0.2, 
    line_opacity=0.7,
    legend_name='Average dust concentration',
    smooth_factor=0)

# display map
pm_testmap
```

[image]